# show custom taxonomies in hierarchy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I am developing a theme and here is what i want to achieve:

Lets say I have a taxonomy hierarchy as follows:

```
-sports
  --bats
  --pads
  --balls
-surgical
  --scissors
etc.
```

How can I shows posts according to the hierarchy in my taxonomy-{slug}.php file with proper taxonomy heading.

Comment: So basically, in your taxonomy template, if you are on the `balls` term, your heading should be something like *Spots>>Balls*

Comment: yes @PieterGoosen, but all the posts in their respective taxonomy just like archive.php file but posts should be categorized in their respective terms